# How can we improve the chat room description?

Tags: discussion, chat

Currently, it's

> General discussion for android.stackexchange.com

which is accurate but a bit... flat. I think it could be improved in two ways:

1. It could be more inviting. The description is our opportunity to really sell the room, get our target audience interested, make them realise how fun we are and the interesting discussions we have. Right now I'm afraid it's just telling people *exactly* how fun we are.
2. It could set the topic better. Just like the main site, we get programmers asking programming questions every so often. The thing is, most of these people know that ASE isn't for them: they come in and post a link to their question on SO, because they've not understood that SO has its own chat system on chat.stackoverflow.com. I've heard rumours that the two chat servers will be unified Real Soon Now, but as a programmer myself I know better than to pin my hopes on vapourware. I think a description that described the topic itself, not just a link to the site, would help visitors to realise that it isn't the right place to get more attention for their questions on SO.

I think the electronic engineering room has a good description, which is open and friendly but still focuses on the topic and sets an ethos for the room.

> A place to talk with friends from the EE community about vacuum nanotubes ... and beer..

Could we have something this good? What are your ideas?

Comment: An extra +1 for the conclusion to 1) :D And full ack. The EEE (Electronic Engineering Ethos) is a very good base indeed!

Answer (score 2):

I'm terrible at naming things like this, but a lot of the other chat rooms use amusing names to try to mix things up. One that popped into my head was something like:

> **The Candy Shop**
>
> A chat room for Android users to discuss devices, apps, the latest Android news and gossip, and how many warranties they've voided.

Something that plays with the idea of Android releases being named after deserts and such. The description is intended to be a little more friendly but also informational. We probably do need to be conscious of the fact that the room listings only get you 40-50 characters before they truncate (you can see the full description by viewing the room info, though). Therefore, keeping the word "users" (or something like that) near the front of the description might be a good idea.

Also, by not calling it "Android" we might help prevent people with programming questions from getting sucked in.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon the "EEE" (Electronic Engineering Ethos) given by Dan:

> A place for Android *Users* from Android.SE, their friends, and their guests to talk about Android … and candies like JellyBeans, Kitkats …

Depending on how long the string is allowed to be, we could explicitely add something like

> … Developers are welcome to *listen*

Or even directly point them to the "correct room".

Answer (score 1):

I agree that we need clearer description about our chat room.

Currently, it doesn't really tell anything, including the misunderstanding between general topic and programming-related (also, as seen on the main site...). The least we can do is to make them notice before they enter the room, which is the job for chat room's description.

As for the name, actually I don't really have an issue with it. Of course, unique and memorable name is better if possible.

My idea is more-or-less like this:

> **Droid Lover**
>
> A place to have general discussion about [Android](http://android.stackexchange.com). If you have a problem related to Android app development, please go to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) or its [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com). Finally, relax, and enjoy the sweets!

<sub>(feedback and corrections are really appreciated since I'm not a native speaker)</sub>